# How to sort a part of an element string?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I've got a problem with some XSLT transformations.
In my XML data there are some Coordinate Elements like this:

XML:

```
[...]
<polygon some="attributes">
  <coordinates>
    <point>(8.234/9.435)</point>
    <point>(2.456/5.678)</point>
    [...]
  </coordinates>
</polygon>
[...]
```

And so on.
The value of  represents an x and a y coordinate (x/y).
Now I have to get from specific coordinate sets the biggest or the smallest value of x OR y.

We are using msxml in our c++ code so I can't use XSLT 2.0 or XPath 2.0 for min() and max() functions.

The format (x/y) is static and I cant change it as well, because it's an output of a program.

I tried to do it in XSLT like this:

XSLT:

```
<xsl:template name="getMinOf"> <!--this one is getting nodeset, min/max, x/y params-->
  <xsl:for-each select="$nodeSet"> <!--in this case "//polygon/coordinates/point"-->
    *<xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$MinOrMax = 'min' ">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="$XorY = 'x'">*
        <xsl:sort select="substring-before(substring-after(.,'('),'/')" data-type="number" order="ascending"/> <!--Here is my problem-->
              <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
                <xsl:value-of select="." /><!--  return xMin -->
              </xsl:if>
          </xsl:when>
      [...]
</xsl:template>
```

The select="**substring-before(substring-after(.,'('),'/')"** should get the part between ( and /, the x coordinate.
If i do a

```
<!--this one does return the x value.-->
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(.,'('),'/')"/>
```

So... I hope you can understand my problem and can help me. I don't know how to get further.
Thanks.

Edit: 
Forgot the desired output. It should be something like this:

```
<polygon>
  <xMin>2.456</xMin>
  <xMax>8.234</xMax>
  <yMin>5.678</yMin>
  <yMax>9.435</yMax>
</polygon>
```

Comment: Can you please update with desired output for the provided input xml ?

Comment: add desired output: check ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although not mentioned in the question, I am guessing your issue is that your are getting the message "Keyword xsl:sort may not be used here.", which occurs because your **xsl:sort** is nested within an **xsl:when** when it should be directly under the **xsl:for-each**

Effectively you are trying to do conditional sorting, based on your parameter. One condition is whether to sort on either the x or y co-ordinate, and the other whether to sort ascending or descending.

For the ordering, you can define a variable, which will holding either 'ascending' or 'descending', and then order by that:

```
  <xsl:variable name="order">
     <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$MinOrMax='max'">descending</xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>ascending</xsl:otherwise>
     </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:for-each select="coordinates/point">
     <xsl:sort select="substring-before(substring-after(.,'('),'/')" data-type="number" order="{$order}"/>
```

The next issue is how to do select either the 'x' or 'y' co-ordinate based on your parameter. One way could be to have a **xsl:choose** to choose between the sorting methods

```
  <xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="$XorY='x'">
        <xsl:for-each select="coordinates/point">
           <xsl:sort select="substring-before(substring-after(.,'('),'/')" data-type="number" order="{$order}"/>
           <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
              <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(.,'('),'/')"/>
           </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>         
     </xsl:when>
     <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:for-each select="coordinates/point">
           <xsl:sort select="substring-before(substring-after(.,'/'),')')" data-type="number" order="{$order}"/>
           <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
              <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(.,'/'),')')"/>
           </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>         
     </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
```

However, there is a way to avoid this potential code duplication, and have a single **xsl:for-each**. Try this for the sort

```
     <xsl:sort select="concat(
          substring(substring-before(substring-after(.,'('),'/'), 1, 100 * ($XorY = 'x')), 
          substring(substring-before(substring-after(.,'/'),')'), 1, 100 * ($XorY = 'y')))" 
       data-type="number" order="{$order}"/>
```

This takes advantage of the fact that `($XorY = 'x')` will evaluate to either 0 or 1 in the expression. To understand it more, it is effectively doing a concatenation of these two expressions:

```
substring(<x co-ordinate>, 1, 100 * <0 or 1>)
substring(<y co-ordinate>, 1, 100 * <0 or 1>)
```

When $XorY = 'x' then 1 is returned, so the first substring (the x co-ordinate) returns a full string, but the second substring returns an empty string. When $XorY = 'y' the opposite is true and the second substring (the y co-ordinate) is returned.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="polygon">
      <polygon>
         <xMin>
            <xsl:call-template name="getMinOf">
               <xsl:with-param name="MinOrMax" select="'min'" />
               <xsl:with-param name="XorY" select="'x'" />
            </xsl:call-template>   
         </xMin>
         <xMax>
            <xsl:call-template name="getMinOf">
               <xsl:with-param name="MinOrMax" select="'max'" />
               <xsl:with-param name="XorY" select="'x'" />
            </xsl:call-template>   
         </xMax>
         <yMin>
            <xsl:call-template name="getMinOf">
               <xsl:with-param name="MinOrMax" select="'min'" />
               <xsl:with-param name="XorY" select="'y'" />
            </xsl:call-template>   
         </yMin>         
         <yMax>
            <xsl:call-template name="getMinOf">
               <xsl:with-param name="MinOrMax" select="'max'" />
               <xsl:with-param name="XorY" select="'y'" />
            </xsl:call-template>   
         </yMax>
      </polygon>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template name="getMinOf">
      <xsl:param name="MinOrMax"/>
      <xsl:param name="XorY"/>
      <xsl:variable name="order">
         <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$MinOrMax='max'">descending</xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>ascending</xsl:otherwise>
         </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:for-each select="coordinates/point">
         <xsl:sort select="concat(substring(substring-before(substring-after(.,'('),'/'), 1, 100 * ($XorY = 'x')), substring(substring-before(substring-after(.,'/'),')'), 1, 100 * ($XorY = 'y')))" data-type="number" order="{$order}"/>
         <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(substring-before(substring-after(.,'('),'/'), 1, 100 * ($XorY = 'x')), substring(substring-before(substring-after(.,'/'),')'), 1, 100 * ($XorY = 'y')))"/>
         </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your sample XML, the following is output

```
<polygon>
   <xMin>2.456</xMin>
   <xMax>8.234</xMax>
   <yMin>5.678</yMin>
   <yMax>9.435</yMax>
</polygon>
```

Comment: Awesome! 
Thank you for this. Works very fine in my code. 
Now, the only part I didn't understand is this one:

concat(
substring(substring-before
  (substring-after(.,'('),'/'), 1, 100 * ($XorY = 'x')), 
substring(substring-before
  (substring-after(.,'/'),')'), 1, 100 * ($XorY = 'y')))

Comment: Ok, I've got it. Thank you for help.